# how to get an object instead of string in js function from an html event

Tags: angularjs, html

The code for the js function is this:

```
   //Set the index of theater array 
   $scope.setTheaterValue = function(name) {
       var index = $scope.path.map(function(s){return s.name}).indexOf(name);
       $scope.path = $scope.path[index].theater;    
   }
```

And html code is this:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-init="init()">
    <md-autocomplete flex="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-input-minlength="2" md-selected-item="geoVal" ng-model="geoVal" md-selected-item-change="setTheaterValue(item.name,theater)" md-autofocus md-autocomplete-snap md-require-match="true" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" md-autoselect="true" md-select-on-match="true" md-no-cache="true" md-floating-label="Select geo">
        <md-item-template>
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
        </md-item-template>
    </md-autocomplete>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

How to pass that theatre as an object so that i can dynamically change the path.
Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I am getting the values of geo and then the theatre array is inside the geo as object and I have to set the path whic I want to do istead of writing that "theatre" here:  $scope.path = $scope.path[index].theater; like $scope.path[index].obj_param_passed_frm_function;

Comment: You are passing `threature` as object in ` md-selected-item-change="setTheaterValue(item.name,theater)"` .. change function to `$scope.setTheaterValue = function(name, thr)` and thr is the threature object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller function as below. this will allow you controller funtion to receive theater along with name

```
 $scope.setTheaterValue = function(name, theater) {

       $scope.path = theater;
   }
```

then you need to pass your **item.theater** instead of **theater** in html

```
    <div layout-gt-sm="row" ng-init="init()">
        <md-autocomplete flex="" md-input-name="autocompleteField" md-input-minlength="2" md-selected-item="geoVal" ng-model="geoVal" 
md-selected-item-change="setTheaterValue(item.name,item.theater)" md-autofocus md-autocomplete-snap md-require-match="true" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.name" md-autoselect="true" md-select-on-match="true" md-no-cache="true" md-floating-label="Select geo">
            <md-item-template>
                <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            </md-item-template>
        </md-autocomplete>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
```